Update ART runtime manually (A12 > up-to-date)
So we have A12 for our SoC.
There are a lot of crush reports regarding ART runtime.
Considering it's a Mainline module (https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/modular-system) since A12, I'd like to update it.
I know for sure there are ART runtime updates for all devices since A12.
But I don't see any merges/cherry-picks to A12 /art branches like:

android12-dev
android12-mainline-art-release
android12-security-release
android-mainline-12.0.0_r126

Also, in Google bug-tracker issues often affect multiple Android versions and they fix them regardless.
So I think they build it in the latest tree and ship those APEXes to be installed via PackageManager.
They link some system static libs like libc++.so, libcrypto.so, etc, but also carry a few libs themselves.
But seems like they work roughly speaking like APKs, not being hard-wired to the OS version.
What is the easier approach to update ART runtime manually?

We're currently having Flattened APEX, the default configuration.
https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/apex#flattening-apex

So I can't try to install an external apex file to check if it works.
Can we download some late AOSP, e.g. A14, build new apex-es as a part of a system image, and copy it to our project (to /system/apex)?
https://android.googlesource.com/platform//art/+/master/build/README.md#building-as-part-of-the-base-system-image

Or do we have to migrate to non-flattened APEXes?
But we would still probably need to build it in a new AOSP Android tree.

